# Is there a word for dried blueberries?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are words for dried grapes and dried plums; *raisins* and *prunes*. Is there a word for dried blueberries, which is also common as a fruit?

As an example,

> I am having _________, which are dried blueberries.

Comment: Nope.  You'll just have to coin *blaisins* to go with *craisins.*

Comment: @stevesliva how do I coin my own word?!

Comment: Not English: bakwasataizatal is the Abenaki word.

Comment: If Grapes seem to drop the G and keep the ra... and affix isons; then by that logic it should be Luisons.

Comment: Dried blueberries are common? Really? I don’t think I’ve ever seen dried blueberries in my life – I hadn’t even considered the possibility of their existence before reading this question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dried_fruit) says

> Nearly half of the dried fruits sold are *raisins*, followed by *dates*, *prunes*, **figs, apricots, peaches, apples and pears**. These are referred to as "conventional" or "traditional" dried fruits: fruits that have been dried in the sun or in heated wind tunnel dryers. Many fruits such as cranberries, **blueberries**, cherries, strawberries and mango are infused with a sweetener (e.g. sucrose syrup) prior to drying.

Note there is no word for dried apricots, peaches, figs, apples or pears. Likewise there is no word for dried blueberries.

[image]