# Besides raisins, what other dried fruits and vegetables have their own names?

Tags: food

Dried grapes¹ have their own special word: "raisins". There are a few words for different types of dried meats ("jerky", "prosciutto", etc.). But other than "raisin", I can't think of any special words for dried fruits or vegetables. Dried apples are just "dried apples". Dried tomatoes are "sun-dried tomatoes". And so forth.

Is "raisin" the only word of this kind, or are there any others? Since this seems to be a scarce type of word, I would count foreign language words if they're used at least occasionally as loan-words.

¹ <sub>I see from the answer to this more-specific question ( [Is there a word for dried blueberries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278342/is-there-a-word-for-dried-blueberries) ) that "raisin" can also be used as a word for some other dried fruits. The question also reminded me that there are a few recently coined words such as "craisin", which suggests that older words of this type are scarce.</sub>

Comment: In BrE, I believe, raisins, or at least a certain type of raisins (the yellow ones) have another special name: *sultanas*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dried_foods#Dried_fruit

Comment: @Dan Bron, that's how I meant to edit it. Thanks. I don't think I have the privilege (anywhere on Stack Exchange) to edit someone else's question, so I didn't expect someone else to do it for me.

Comment: @Steve No problem. That's what we're here for. Every post is a community effort, and quality is everyone's responsibility.

Comment: @Steve Lerida, Baglama, Protoben, and Garland dried figs, just to name a few... https://books.google.fr/books?id=zbNNAAAAMAAJ&q=Lerida,+Protoben,+Baglama,+garland+dried+figs&dq=Lerida,+Protoben,+Baglama,+garland+dried+figs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwu4jh-rbLAhXDVxoKHTp0ALsQ6AEIHTAA

Comment: @Elian those are not recognized in the US

Comment: @Mitch How about Medjool dates?

Comment: @Elian yes medjool but it seems only recently because being sold by that name a lot in US grocery stores in the past 5 years. But that word doesn't mean 'dried dates' just a variety of dates. No concern that they're dried.

Comment: There's "banana chips", though that's two words, and includes the original un-dried fruit in the name.  Still, I've never heard any other fruit called "chips" when dried.  (There's "corn chips", but there's a lot more involved in those than simply drying corn.)

Comment: Peppercorns are dried berries, but we never eat them in non-dried form.

Comment: Prunes came to mind as soon as I saw the question in the sidebar.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman "apple chips"?  Apples dried until they're crispy (they porbably start off as thinner slices than the spongy sort of dried apple.

Comment: Is the term "anjeer" recognized and commonly used in the West? Anjeer is the Hindi word for figs.

Comment: off topic: in Austria and Bavaria there is a special name for dried pears: [Kletze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kletze). This dried pears are used for a sweet bread baked before christmas that is called [Kletzenbrot](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%BCchtebrot).

Answer (score 51):

One obvious answer is *sultanas* (AKA golden raisins, defined as dried white grapes - [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sultana)). A better answer is *prunes* (dried plums - [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prune) ) . Interestingly *raisin* and *prune* are both the French name for the matching undried fruit.

Another oddity is *currant* both a small raisin and (black-, white-, or red-) a completely different fruit ([Cambridge again](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/currant)).

They're not dried but *gherkins* are worth a mention too.

Comment: +1 for prunes. That should have occurred to me immediately. Can you please [edit] in some references and dictionary definitions for the two words you suggest? We prefer answers - even obviously correct answers - offer some authoritative citations, so people not in the know can distinguish fact from opinion.

Comment: Prunes! Of course. An interesting thing about "prune" is that it can also refer to an un-dried fruit. Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prune , citing the OED) says that usage is obsolete except for varieties grown for drying, but I've certainly heard people refer to prunes as an un-dried fruit distinct from plums, so maybe it's not as obsolete as the OED says.

Comment: @Chris H, speaking of limitations on mobile, I could stand to edit my question (next time I'm on a regular computer) to use the asterisk and the link to the earlier question so it looks nicer.

Comment: Weird thing about prunes is I've seen both "prune juice" and "plum juice" sold in stores.  I can't imagine what the difference could be since they're the same fruit...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Prune juice is dried plum juice, presumably. :-p

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Prune "juice" is generally an extract of dried plums (prunes). I've never had "plum juice" but prune juice has taste and consistency different from what I would imagine a plum juice would taste like (based on how the fresh fruit tastes).

Comment: "I can't imagine what the difference could be" -- how odd, as imagining that is very easy to do. I would expect prune juice to be more concentrated. Also, the fruit cells undergo chemical changes during drying that I would expect to result in significant taste differences between the two, just as prunes and plums taste quite different. And even if you have no imagination at all, there's always google: https://www.google.com/search?q=prune%20juice%20vs%20plum%20juice

Comment: Re: "raisin and prune" : historically, if you were going to export perishable goods from France to England, you'd better preserve them first, by drying. So the French name naturally becomes associated with the dried fruit and the native name with the fresh fruit.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I like that description, I don't suppose you have a source for it do you?

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: Imagination is not needed when you can perform an experiment.  Buy some prune juice and some plum juice, taste both.  You'll now know the difference :-)

Answer (score 40):

A number of Spanish names for chili peppers have migrated into English (at least in parts of the western and southwestern United States, where many types of chilies are sold in fruit and vegetable markets). Three varieties of these peppers have different names when fresh and when dry:

- *poblano* chilies (fresh) are called *ancho* chilies (dried)
- *chilaca* chilies (fresh) are called *pasilla* chilies (dried)
- *jalapeño* peppers (fresh) are called *morita* or *chipotle* peppers (smoked & dried)

A book called [*12 Essential Chili Peppers for Mexican Cooking*](http://pocketchangegourmet.com/12-essential-chile-peppers-for-mexican-cooking/) shows pictures of some of these peppers.

Whether you're inclined to view these words as foreign or as naturalized English depends on where you live and how interested you are in Mexican-style cooking. (The same goes for words like *enchilada*, *tamale*, *taco*, and *molé*, I suppose.) In the San Francisco Bay Area, the words *ancho*, *pasilla*, and *chipotle* are widely recognized; *morita* is probably less familiar. I have seen all of the pepper varieties listed above (except fresh chilacas) for sale at the vegetable market where I shop.

Comment: A strong point in favor of the view that a word has been naturalized is the [existence of a brand](https://www.chipotle.com/). +1

Comment: Chipotles are dried jalapeños?! Today I learnt!

Comment: Chipotles are not necessarily dried. The ones you buy canned in adobo sauce are not. I believe a chipotle is a jalapeno that has been allowed to ripen before picking, and is usually roasted.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I believe that the canned chipotles that you are talking about are remoisturized by the adobo sauce that they are packed in, much as sun-dried tomatoes in jars of olive oil are. Previously, however, the peppers are dried by being smoked for several days in an enclosed smoking chamber. You can read about the process on the ["Chipotle" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipotle). You're right that jalapeños destined to become chipotles are allowed to ripen to redness, which (Wikipedia says) also leads to their being drier than green jalapeños, even before smoking.

Comment: The _Austin [Texas] Chronicle_ has an interesting article about the varieties of [chipotle chiles](http://www.austinchronicle.com/daily/food/2012-08-26/chipotle-chiles/) that are produced in Mexico (and Texas) and about the process of producing them—including a paragraph on chipotles canned in adobo sauce.

Answer (score 33):

Goji berries are dried wolfberries (*Lycium barbarum*)

If you saw a fresh wolfberry and you knew it looked like the thing on a packet of something that contained "Goji berries", you might call the fresh berry a Goji berry too, but actually Goji are always dried. The name comes from Chinese where Goji is specifically the name of the dried berry.

Comment: I ask a really good question about "inlining functions in python" that took me hours to research on Stack Overflow and it gets 2 down votes and 3 upvotes. I blow the whistle on academic fraud in Academia.SE and i get 4 downvotes and 5 upvotes. I post about goji berries in English.SE and I get 18 upvotes and no downvotes -_-; Why can't every site be as nice as you guys.

Comment: Because I for one didn't know that Goji berries were wolfberry, in the pat of Italy where I'm from, the former is a relatively newcomer. I had to look up wolfberries on Google to see what they looked like :)

Answer (score 12):

The trademarked word Craisins® has been coined to refer to Ocean Spray's specific brand of sweetened dried cranberries, however you will also see the word being used generically for any form of dried cranberries.

Answer (score 12):

Prunes for plums is another option.

The dried, wrinkled fruit of certain species of plum.

Answer (score 5):

[Dried apricot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dried_apricot) was historically an important commodity along the Silk Road because of its long shelf life without refrigeration. Words for it were borrowed into Russian: *kuragá* (stress on the last syllable) and *uryúk* (likewise), the difference being that the latter is dried with the pit still inside. No similar term exists for English, although I wonder if perhaps Hindi or Urdu borrowed such words, in which case they could make their way into the local English vocabulary.

Incidentally, *'Due to the popular U.S. perception of [prunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prune#Name) being used only for relief of constipation, and being the subject of related joking, many distributors stopped using the word "prune" on packaging labels in favour of* [... drumroll ...]  "dried plums".'

Answer (score 4):

I had the same idea as [choster](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/16052/choster) and looked at [Wikipedia's list of dried foods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dried_foods#Plant_foods).

I found two more words you might want to consider.
I checked the Cambridge Dictionaries, Collins dictionary, Oxford Dictionaries and Merriam Webster and listed their entries where applicable alongside Wikipedia's description

---

## Ristra

[Ristra – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ristra)

> "A ristra is an arrangement of drying chili pepper pods. [...] Garlic can also be arranged into a ristra".

[Ristra – Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ristra)

> "a string of dried chilli peppers, sometimes used as decoration
>
> **Origin**
>
> Late 19th century; earliest use found in Los Angeles Daily Times.
> From Spanish ristra string, especially a string of garlic or onions, later also of chillies, etc., ultimately from classical Latin restis."

[Ristra – Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ristra)

> "A string or garland of dried chillis or other produce, often used as a decoration."

---

## Chuño

[Chuño – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%C3%B1o)

> "a freeze-dried potato product traditionally  made by [...][repeatedly] exposing a frost-resistant variety of potatoes to the very low night temperatures of the Andean Altiplano, freezing them,
> and subsequently exposing them to the intense sunlight of the day".

[Chuño – Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chuno):
Only listed in their paid unabridged dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK at least, he simple term *date* refers to the dried fruit. The more rarely seen (and higher-priced) fresh dates are always referred to as such.

Comment: date is also the name of the un-dried fruit, and of the palm tree